# Carregamento em etapas para página index da aplicação

Tags: jsf

Possuo uma aplicação comercial que está com um login extremamente demorado para o usuário. A conexão ao Banco de Dados para validar usuário e senha, bem como a inicialização do Spring Security levam em torno de 0.8 segundos, o que está ótimo.

O problema é o carregamento da página principal, que exibe gráficos e tabelas e a conexão ao Banco chega a ultrapassar 20 segundos. A consulta é feita na inicialização do Bean e só após o retorno, a página exibida muda. Para o usuário, não existe feedback enquanto isso é feito e fica a impressão de que a aplicação travou.

Chamada do método da Página Principal:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{paginaInicialBean.inicializar()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Já fiz testes com `@PostConstruct`, métodos javascript como `window.onload` ou com a palavra "*defer*", mas todos apresentam o mesmo comportamento já oferecido pelo schema core do JSF (f:).

Pensei em fazer um carregamento em etapas, como o Gmail possui, mas não tive sucesso na implementação. Outra opção seria exibir meu template (Menu superior) e só então chamar o método da Página Principal, assim o usuário sabe que algo está sendo carregado e se não quiser esperar, pode sair navegando pelo menu.

Alguém já teve essa dificuldade?

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isto eu sugiro que você abra a página sem executar o método `#{paginaInicialBean.inicializar()}`, e somente depois de a página estar carregada você executar um Ajax que inicialize os dados e atualize o conteúdo da tela.

Para fazer isto siga os seguintes passos:

- Remova o `<f:viewAction>` de inicialização da tag `<f:metadata>`
- Crie um `<h:commandLink>` com um `id` qualquer e com `style="display:none"` (para ficar invisível) que execute o método `#{paginaInicialBean.inicializar()}` na tag `<f:ajax>`
- Na tag `<f:ajax>` indique quais elementos da tela devem ser atualizados no atributo `render` e chame o método `#{paginaInicialBean.inicializar()}` no atributo `listener`
- Por fim, execute uma função JavaScript que execute um click no `<h:commandLink>` quando a página tiver sido carregada por completo.

Realizando isto a página irá ser acessada rapidamente, e depois que o conteúdo será carregado. Segue abaixo um snippet para melhor análise:

```
<h:head>
    <script>
        //Este é o código JavaScript que irá executar e chamar o clique no seu h:commandLink quando a página tiver sido carregada
        //Note que o id do botão precisa ser o id form, dois pontos e id do botão 'idDoForm:idDoBotao'
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('pagina:botaoCarregarDados').click();
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="pagina">
        <h:panelGroup id="conteudoDaPagina">
            <!-- Aqui ficaria o conteúdo dinâmico de sua página -->
        </h:panelGroup>            

        <!-- Abaixo fica o botão que irá carregar os dados da sua página de forma dinâmica -->
        <h:commandLink id="botaoCarregarDados" style="display: none;">
            <f:ajax listener="#{paginaInicialBean.inicializar()}" render=":conteudoDaPagina"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Você pode também executar alguma função JavaScript que bloqueie a tela enquanto o conteúdo é carregado, mas fica a seu critério.

Esta pergunta já foi respondida no StackOverflow "original". Segue link abaixo da pergunta (em inglês): [Execute managebean method from javascript onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522702/execute-managebean-method-from-javascript-onload-event)